# Solr query time join

Tags: solr, solr4

I am attempting to do a join on two fields that have the same name (company_id) but are from different entities to query a document based on a field it does not have.

ex: I have a sales entity and a company entity, where the sales entity holds a company id, and the company entity holds the name of the company.

For size reasons, I cannot do this join at index time.

I wish to get the names of the companies that have a sale over `x`.

I attempted both of the following:

```
q={!join+from=company_id+to=company_id}sales:[100 TO *]
```

and

```
fq={!join+from=company_id+to=company_id}sales:[100 TO *]
```

For the `fq` one I just specified `*:*` as the `q` parameter.

In both cases I got results, but the results did not have sales in that range.

How can I fix this?

Using Solr 4.4

**Note:** This appears to work with only one entity involved.

Answer (score 0):

With "different entities" are you referring to 2 Solr Core ?
In that case you have use a slight different sintax :

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/<coreTO>/select?q={!join from=docId to=id fromIndex=<coreFROM>}query
```

Comment: No, I mean multiple entities (more than one set of <entity/> tags)

Answer (score 0):

From this link [Solr-join](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-JoinQueryParser)

I have found the solution.

According to this :

The join operation is done on a term basis, so the "from" and "to" fields must use compatible field types.  For example: joining between a StrField and a TrieIntField will not work, likewise joining between a StrField and a TextField that uses LowerCaseFilterFactory will only work for values that are already lower cased in the string field.

Comment: the "from" and "to" fields type should be the same.
Like below : 
 <field name="xxxx" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="yyyy" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>